# how to sum the value in a matrix element or within square brackets[ ]

Tags: perl

suppose i have a value 2 
to be **added to the matrix or range** having
**[ 99 to 103 ]
[ 267 to 271 ]**
 what's is the method of doing it ?

expected output:[ 101 to 105 ]
                [ 269 to 273 ].

i have already fetch the range ..here is the code.

```
enter code here
$input= $argv[0];
open($file,"$input");
while($line=<$file>)
{ 
  $ranges.=$line if($line=~m/\[/);  
  print   $ranges, 
 if 
         ($line=~m/----------------------------------------------------------------------/);
 }
```

i want to add 2 to the matrix .thanks for any help

**input file:**

```
>13pk_A: starts from 5
ITNDYRIRSALPTLKKVLTEGGSCVLMSHLGRPKGIPMAQAGKIRSTGGVPGFQQKATL
Total number of repeat(s) = 2
The length of repeat = 4
Number of residues in the repeat = 4
KKVL        z0
[ 13 to 16 ]
[ 44 to 47 ]
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: See also [Extract data between square brackets using Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991032/extract-data-between-square-brackets-using-perl)

Comment: Your code is incorrect, Provide a mininmal working example.

Comment: code is working correctly for me...how to do addition of a number within square brackets in perl... @Raju

Comment: use strict and use warnings;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;

use warnings;

my $file = "path\\data.txt";

open (my $fh, "<", $file) or die "can't open this file";

my $number = 4;

while ( my $line = <$fh>){

    if ( $line =~ /\[\s(\d*)\sto\s(\d*)\s]/){

        my $first_range = int($1);
        $first_range = $1 + $number;

        my $second_range = int($2);
        $second_range = $2 + $number;

        print "\n[ $first_range to $second_range ]";
    }
}
```

The regex will store in `$1` and `$2` the two ranges.

```
$line =~ /\[\s(\d*)\sto\s(\d*)\s]/
```

Base on the input pattern  `[ number to number ]`.

```
int($1);
```

This will convert the string to integer.

```
$first_range = $1 + $number;
```

Adds to your range the number which you want ( i hardcoed it to be 4, `my $number = 4`).

Comment: Why not use `my @ranges = ( $line =~ /\[\s(\d*)\sto\s(\d*)\s]/);` ? The conversion to int will be automatic when you add the number to `$ranges[0]` for example.

Comment: I did not knew this trick, feel free to edit my answer! Thank you for this knowledge!